# AWS web app (running) accessible in one region but same not available in other region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

One AWS instance is running in the following zone: eu-west-1a.

The website can be accessed in UK but the same website is not accessible in India.

As I am new to AWS environment, I do not know if I am missing any setting. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the AWS provided URL or IP address? Also if you are using your own domain name, how is it registered via AWS Route 53 or some other provider?

Comment: Also, what does "not accessible" mean? Can you provide output showing a curl request, for instance?

Comment: @vmachan: I am using public IP address. I have configured the IP address in names.co.uk site where I have purchased my domain.

Comment: @tedder42 I mean when I enter the domain in browser, the site cannot be accessed in India. But the same site can be accessed in UK by using same  domain name. Isn't it strange ?

Comment: please show a curl request, as well as a host/nslookup example.